# Filter array by index and save it to another array

Tags: android

I´m trying to filter all values in name where id = 1 and save to an array.

This is the output I get from my WS:

[{id=1; name=Des Moines; }, {id=2; name=Cedar Rapids; }, {id=3; name=Yakima; },{id=4; name=Fort Dodge; }, {id=1; name=Iowa City; }]

if I try get property it splits my content.

Could anyone help me out on how to get the desire output?

Answer (score 2):

That's JSON data, you should consider parse the data into an object , there are a lot of JSON java parsers , you could read something about GSON:

https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following
your json string must be like:

["items":{id=1; name=Des Moines; }, {id=2; name=Cedar Rapids; }, {id=3; name=Yakima; },{id=4; name=Fort Dodge; }, {id=1; name=Iowa City; }]

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
jsonObject = new JSONObject("your json string goes here!!");
String items = jsonObject.getString("items");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(weather);
ArrayList<JSONObject > arrList = new ArrayList<JSONObject >();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
    arrList.add(jsonObject1 );
    String id = jsonObject1.get("id").toString();
    String name = jsonObject1.get("name").toString();

}
```